# SVN plugin for eclipse 4.14

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

Is there any SVN plugin compatible with the latest version of eclipse IDE ?

eclipse version : 4.14

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried both? Which error message did you get for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Subclipse and Subversive. [Subclipse](https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki) is compatible with the latest Eclipse versions.